# MinionPro is erroneous when using beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts

I've installed MinionPro on OSX using the instructions [here](https://www.clarkdonley.com/post/2015-03-installing-minionpro-for-latex-on-mac-os-x-yosemite/), after getting the free version of the font. The code generated too much output to paste here, but it appeared ok. I've then tried the following small working example:

```
% !TeX document-id = {ab57b317-99c9-42bf-84cf-986427da740b}
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    This is a dot: $\dot a$. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the `\dot` is erroneously compiled for me, as can be seen by the following picture. Which part of the installation did I mess up - what can I do to fix this?

[image: Broken tex]

Comment: It seems to be a problem with `beamer`: with, say, the `article` class, there's no problem.

Comment: @Bernard This is a strange one: If you use MinionPro without beamer, it works. If you use beamer with another font, it works as well. MWE here: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{titel}
  \begin{theorem}
      This is a dot: \[\dot{a}\]
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: It doesn't work that well with, say, `lmodern`: beamer, unconcernedly, still uses its sans maths font, and the dot is ill-placed.

Comment: Try \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} (untested).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For whatever reason, that worked! You can set that up as an answer if you wish

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load the `professionalfonts` theme. To quote the documentation:

> `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`
>
> This font theme does not really
>   change any fonts. Rather, it suppresses certain internal replacements
>   performed by beamer. If you use “professional fonts” (fonts that you
>   buy and that come with a complete set of every symbol in all modes),
>   you do not want beamer to meddle with the fonts you use. beamer
>   normally replaces certain character glyphs in mathematical text by
>   more appropriate versions. For example, beamer will normally replace
>   glyphs such that the italic characters from the main font are used for
>   variables in mathematical text. If your professional font package
>   takes care of this already, beamer’s meddling should be switched off.